# How can i locate a postion in map for my application uses?

Tags: android, google-maps, gps, position

---

### how i should locate a position in map ?

ok , so i want to locate my gate position in the park and to call the gate automaticly when i am about 50 meters far away from the position of the gate,  i think i may start with determine the position of the gate in maps by google-maps or gps
but i dont realy know how

i tried to see some samples of google maps api , but i cant make it work for some reason .
anyway this should be an app in the end .. and i hope some of you guys will help me in some way

Answer (score 0):

This is the basic you need, you get your latitude and longitude from this, and then you start a new activity by sending "geo:lat,lon" to intent, and that opens your google maps app. And this is a way you could find your current location. You should read more about LocationListener etc on the android developer website.

```
public class GetLocation extends Activity {
LocationManager lm;
LocationListener ll;



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.show_location);

    lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    ll = new MyLocationListener();

    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, ll);

        try {

            double latitude = getLatitude();
            double longitude = getLongitude();
                Uri uri = Uri.parse("geo:"+latitude+","+longitude);

                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri));

                finish();

        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR: "+e);
        }


    }

}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    lm.removeUpdates(ll);
}

public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc){
        loc.getLatitude();
        loc.getLongitude();     

    }


    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) 
    {
    }


    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)
    {
    }


    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)
    {
    }
}
```

}

Comment: tnx alot but its marks this lines as an error:

           `double latitude = getLatitude();
            double longitude = getLongitude();`

Comment: `double latitude = String.valueOf(loc.getLatitude());` and 
    `double longitude = String.valueOf(loc.getLongitude());`